# what's different between 'tailpipe' and 'exhaust'?

Tags: word-difference

what's different between 'tailpipe' and 'exhaust' ?

For example in here :

> Electric vehicles usually look just like normal vehicles on the
>   outside except for the lack of a **tailpipe** and **exhaust** system. - emissionfreecars.com

Comment: Perhaps your confusion is because sometimes the tailpipe is called an exhaust pipe, and those two words mean the same thing if you are talking about a vehicle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an gasoline/petrol powered automobile, the *exhaust* is the waste gas from the internal combustion engine, usually made of carbon dioxide and various hydrocarbons.

The tailpipe is the last part of [the exhaust *system*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exhaust_system).  It is a pipe (or pipes) that come out of the engine, often near the rear of the vehicle, from which the exhaust can vent.

The below image shows exhaust venting from a tailpipe.

[image: exhaust coming out from a tailpipe]

An electric vehicle needs neither -- there is no internal combustion, so there is no waste gas.

Comment: You might mention that a tailpipe is part of an exhaust system (or a system that handles the exhaust).